# Powershell How can I write a Class Method which calls its constructor

Tags: powershell, object

I sum up my request.
Let's say I have a Class which handles a text file and apply a process on some lines.
Among the methods, one extracts a part of the text and should return an instance of this class, but limited to this part of the original file.
So I have a method that will call its own constructor.
I have the feeling that does not work. With an other language, sure, but not in PowerShell.
What I would like to do :

```
Class MyClass {

   MyClass([string[]] lines) {

   }

   [MyClass]MyMethod {
      return [MyClass]::new( somelines)
   }

}

[MyClass]$obj1 = [MyClass]::new( ( get-content "myfile.txt"))
[MyClass]$obj2= $obj1.MyMethod()
```

My solution I dont' like :

```
Class MyClass {

   MyClass([string|]] $lines) {

   }
   [String[]]MyMethod {
       return somelines
   }
}


[MyClass]$obj1 = [MyClass]::new( ( get-content "myfile.txt"))
[string[]]$part = $obj1.MyMethod()
[MyClass]$obj2 = [MyClass]::new( $part)
```

Comment: Aside mispelling `[string|]]`, your first solution works perfectly.   
I suppose you were thinking of having it being a Nullable? That'd be `[System.Nullable[String]]` IIRC

Comment: @sirtao there is no need to specify output type as nullable in powershell classes, it already performs that coercion automatically: `class Test { static [string[]] Method() { return $null }}; [Test]::Method()`

Comment: Well, I didn't know classes did that automatically. Good to know!

Comment: @sirtao, the mispelling was just a mistake I made in this example. I edited the example to fix it. The constructor is empty just because I thought its code was not the purpose of my question.

Answer (score 2):

What you describe is perfectly doable:

```
class MyClass {
  [string[]]$Lines

  MyClass([string[]]$lines){
    $this.Lines = $lines
  }

  [MyClass]MyMethod([int]$from, [int]$to) {
    if ($from -lt 0) {
      throw [System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException]::new('from')
    }
    if ($to -lt $from -or $to -ge $this.Lines.Count) {
      throw [System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException]::new('to')
    }

    return [MyClass]::new($this.Lines[$from..$to])
  }
}
```

Example:

```
$fileContents = @'
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
'@ -split '\r?\n'

$myInstance = [MyClass]::new($fileContents)
$mySubset = $myInstance.MyMethod(1, 3)

$myInstance.Lines # returns `Line1` through `Line 5`
$mySubset.Lines   # returns `Line2` through `Line 4`
```

Comment: Well, your example works fine ! That's what I wanted to do. I don't know why it didn't work. I could simplify a lot my code !